# How should I use manual partition in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, installation

Well , I'm just moving from Windows platform to Ubuntu and I'm stuck at how to use manual partition. I don't want to preserve any previous windows installation or previous data too. My Windows drives were as follows :

1. Local Drive C : [200 GB] (approx) : Contained Windows + Other Softwares
2. Local Drive D : [200 GB] (approx) : Contained my development stuff ( different projects in different folders with git init )
3. Local Drive E : [What's Left] : Games.

If I need to follow somewhat same scheme in Ubuntu Installation , how should I proceed?

Specs if needed : HDD [500GB] , RAM[4GB] , Processor[ Intel Core i3 2.5ghz ]

Comment: Do you have any particular reason to not [use automatic partitioning, as suggested in the documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/howto-installation.html)?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling the thing is I'll have to use Replace Windows with Ubuntu as an alternative to this , which will create the entire disk as one partition. I am thinking of a directory structure resembling to my previous Windows Installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always a lot of arguing about partition layouts. I tend towards having as few partitions as needed to suit your needs. I don't know what the Ubuntu default is at the moment. So here first my recommendation for you:

Put everything on the same partition except /home. If you do not want to store your dev-data in the home folder, put it on a individual partition too. This gives you the option to mount it where ever you like it. However be aware that repartitioning the drive destroys all previously contained data. **So back up your data** and restore it from the backup once you are done with installation.

Depending on your needs you can also move other directories onto their separate partition:

- /usr might go to a SSD so you can get the loading speed
- /var if your main disk is an SSD and you expect a lot of read/write here, move it to a magnetic disk. You also might want to tune the file system
- any additional partitions you may want. I have a machine that I use for ripping optical media. I rip the raw image to one and encode from there to a different disk. I also usually put

If you are considering a more advanced setup involving multiple disk and a number of partitions you might also want to consider using volume manager like LVM or a file system that can do this like BTRFS

Having multiple partitions can have the following benefits:

- Each partition can have its own file-system. Some file-systems perform better under specific kinds of workload.
- You can specify different mount options for each partition
- It is very easy to make a backup of a whole partition
- It prevents interference between different "sections" of storage. Your home-dir can't grow so big that there is no space left to install programs.
- You can take advantage of using multiple drives in parallel if you have I/O heavy workloads.

How ever there a drawbacks too:

- Once a partition is full, resizing can be difficult
- Some setups, like /usr on a separate partition, require pree-userspace mounting by initramfs (Ubuntu Installer takes care of this). This requires additional time on boot.

I hope this was useful to you.

paradoxon

Comment: *No, no, no, no!* **Never** put /root or /etc on their own partitions. You will break a huge number of things especially by putting /etc on a separate partition, because /etc contains /etc/fstab which tells the system where the various file systems -- *including, in this case, /etc* -- are physically located. /root could potentially be put on a separate partition, but if you are storing any significant amount of data there, you are doing something wrong, and it potentially makes system recovery more difficult; there's no upside, and quite a lot of downside, so just don't.

Comment: I had my installation running for years this way. My /boot is on a thumbdrive together with encryption keys, so I need an initramfs anyway. The rest of the system is spread between a magnetic disk and an SSD. So back then I put /etc and /var on a reiserfs (small files) and mounted /etc, /usr as read only to prevent tempering. Yes it is paranoid/extreme but that is why Linux is fun to me. But your are right in this regard that it is not generraly help full to point thhis out to a newbie. I'll edit accordingly.

Comment: Better suited now? :-)

Comment: Much better this way. Oh, and you have a half-finished sentence in the third bullet point in the first list: the one that begins with "I also usually put" and doesn't end with anything.

Answer (score 3):

If you aren't interested in keeping your old files around, and you are new to Linux, I recommend just using the automatic partitioning offered by the Ubuntu installer and telling it to use the whole disk for Linux. **That will wipe *everything*** that is currently on your computer and give you a brand new installation.

Then, restore any documents, photos, source code, etc. that you want to keep from backups. Make sure those backups are readable from Ubuntu before you do this. Plain file copies to an external hard drive that you keep disconnected while installing Linux is usually the easiest (and safest) approach; using more advanced backup software can easily trip you up when you want to copy the files back in a completely different environment.

Unless you are a Linux power user, there is very little reason today to use manual partitioning; and if you were in a position of knowing what to do with that, you likely wouldn't need to ask this kind of question.

If you are offered the choice ([Ubuntu's documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/installation-guide/i386/module-details.html#partman-auto) seems to talk about the choice of a separate partition for /home), then a separate, large partition for /home may be appropriate. That'd allow you to reinstall the operating system without touching your own files later should that be necessary. Almost everything you do yourself on Linux will by default be placed somewhere under /home, and installed software will be in other locations (most will be under /usr). It isn't a requirement, however.

Also, if you aren't concerned about keeping your old files around, or if you have copies, there is nothing (other than time expended) stopping you from trying the installation a few times and seeing what options are offered, before you decide how to lay out your system.